# How can I track subscribers to an event in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, events, event-handling

Is there some hidden class property which would allow to know this ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you have access to the actual delegate (if you're using the shorthand `event` syntax, then this is only within the actual declaring class, as the delegate is `private`), then you can call [`GetInvocationList()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.getinvocationlist.aspx).

For instance:

```
public event EventHandler MyEvent;
```

To get the list of subscribers, you can call:

```
Delegate[] subscribers = MyEvent.GetInvocationList();
```

You can then inspect the `Method` and `Target` properties of each element of the `subscribers` array, if necessary.

The reason this works is because declaring the event as we did above *actually* does something akin to this:

```
private EventHandler myEventDelegate;

public event EventHandler MyEvent
{
    add { myEventDelegate += value; }
    remove { myEventDelegate -= value; }
}
```

This is why the event looks different when viewed from within the declaring class compared to anywhere else (including classes that inherit from it). The only public-facing interface is the `add` and `remove` functionality; the actual delegate, which is what holds the subscriptions, is `private`.