# class expose event, how to know if someone subscribed it

Tags: c#, events

My class implements interface, And I expose event to the outside world.
I have a polling timer that send data using that event to subscriber using a custom eventArgs.
I want to start the polling timer Only when someone has subscribed to the event, and stop the timer when everyone un-subscribed from it.
How can I detect when someone subscribes / un-subscribes from my event ?

This way i can automatically start/stop the polling timer if no one listen.

Comment: take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911009/how-can-i-track-subscribers-to-an-event-in-c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add your own `add`/`remove` methods; for example:

```
private EventHandler someEvent;
public event EventHandler SomeEvent {
    add {
        someEvent += value;
        if(someEvent != null) EnsureTimerRunning();
    }
    remove {
        someEvent -= value;
        if(someEvent == null) StopTimerIfRunning();
    }
}
```

Note that *field-like events* (i.e. `public event EventHandler SomeEvent;`) include compiler-generated thread-safety around `add`/`remove` - you'll need to decide whether to duplicate that, and if so: how (`lock`, `Interlocked`, or just defer to a private backing field-like event and let the compiler worry about it). A very simplistic approach might be:

```
private EventHandler someEvent;
private readonly object syncLock = new object();
public event EventHandler SomeEvent {
    add {
        lock(syncLock) {
            someEvent += value;
            if(someEvent != null) EnsureTimerRunning();
        }
    }
    remove {
        lock(syncLock) {
            someEvent -= value;
            if(someEvent == null) StopTimerIfRunning();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, So they are called Event Accessors. i knew there must be better way other then using the GetInvocationList().

Comment: @ilansch the invocation lists is handy, but in the case of "has / has not got subscribers", that is just a `null` test

Comment: If i implement the Add/Remove, i can no longer check someEvent != null. is there additional "get" accessor i need to add ?

Comment: The line lock(syncLock) {
            someEvent -= value;
            if(someEvent == null) StopTimerIfRunning(); will tell me: The someEvent can only appear on left handside of +/-=

Comment: @ilansch nope; from the outside, events only typically expose `+=` and `-=`; there *are* 2 other accessors defined in the specification, IIRC, but the C# compiler only ever implements `add` and `remove`

Comment: ah i got it, confused this is private event and public property

Comment: @ilansch no it isn't; it is a private field and a public event; it is absolutely **not** a private event and public property